# Add slashes in Area name on an ASP.NET MVC 2 route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

Currently I have an Area in my ASP.NET MVC 2 project call 'API', which is self explanatory.

As the API of my web application matures, I will soon need to add version numbers to my address. ie/

Instead of :

`http://site/API/`

I will need

```
http://site/API/1.0/
http://site/API/1.1/
...
```

What's the best practise to achieve this in ASP.NET MVC (2)?

I'm currently experimenting with an Area call `Api_1_0` and modify its MapRoute to

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Api_1_0_default",
    "Api/1.0/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But appearently the extra slash in the URL causes run time error.

Comment: can you post the error you are getting.

Comment: I kept the mind set of additional slash is causing the trouble, but not realising that I have an existing `Api` area that causes `"Api/1.0/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` to fall into `Api` area route map before it reaches to `Api_1_0` area route map. Thanks so much mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your exact scenario and it seems to be working just fine with the slash

```
            context.MapRoute(
                "Api_1_0_default",
                "Api/1.0/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

[image]